# Confusion with `Array#each` in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Confusion with `Array#each` as below:

```
%w{ david black }.each {|str| str.capitalize }
#=> ["david", "black"]
```

The above code is cool,but how the below logic works,couldn't understand.

```
%w{ david black }.each(&:capitalize)
#=> ["david", "black"]
```

Comment: What specifically are you surprised by? And by the way, using `capitalize` with `.each`  is quite pointless.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I am surprised with the syntax `each(&:capitalize)`. And i think every ruby learner should read each corner of this language features. and I did it,but couldn't understand how that below code worked to produce the correct output.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Not sure what you mean by 'using capitalize with .each is quite pointless.'. Can you explain what you mean by that? Thanks.

Comment: @garbagecollection Yes you are correct,but I think he tried to say why i worte such code.

Comment: The version with `&`has two benefits: There are fewer punctuation characters. You don't need to introduce a temporary name for a variable.

Comment: @garbagecollection: `each` invokes a passed block with every element in the collection and then returns the collection. Return values of the block are ignored. That's why it's pointless.

Comment: @iAmRubuuu: "how that below code worked to produce the correct output" - clearly depends on your definition of "correct output". I would assume that you wanted capitalized strings, no?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, Okay that method name might confused you.what I expected,I was trying to understand how that syntax works,what internally it does.the last code is new to me,thus got confused.

Comment: Down-voter: what made you confused or unclear above? tell me so that i can make it clear.

Comment: 1) why the `irb` line? 2) what's the point of doing `capitalize` within `each`? 3) is it really `each` which the question is about, or is it the ampersand syntax? 4) which logic?

Comment: @MladenJablanović - 1) is done. 3) yes,it is the `&` related. Ignore the syntax `each`.I was trying to understand how `&` is using to call `symbol#to_proc`. 2) and 4) has been answered to 3). Hope it is clear to you. Happy to clear everything which still confusing you. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's a very old trick, called `Symbol#to_proc`.

You can read more about it here: http://pragdave.pragprog.com/pragdave/2005/11/symbolto_proc.html

Basically, it's a shortcut for calling methods that take no args. Often used in `map`, for example.

```
%w[i can measure length of strings].map(&:length) # => [1, 3, 7, 6, 2, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using map?

```
[1173]pry(main)> ["david","black"].map{|str| str.capitalize }
=> ["David","Black"]
[1173]pry(main)>
```

Answer (score 0):

The notation of `&:something` does for every element of the array the method `something`.

This is usually used with map to change every entry of the array or to extract data from hashes.

```
[{:foo => :bar, :meh => :bar2}, {:foo => :one, :meh => :two}].map(&:foo)
=> [:bar, :one]
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't get your example with .each, maybe you meant .map

When you pass in the &:method_name it's shorthand for doing it in the block. So for each item apply this method.